# Can the foreign data wrapper fdw_postgres handle the GEOMETRY data type of PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, foreign-data-wrapper

I am accessing data from a different DB via *fdw_postgres*. It works well:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE fdw_table 
(
  name TEXT,
  area double precision,
  use TEXT,
  geom GEOMETRY
)
SERVER foreign_db 
OPTIONS (schema_name 'schema_A', table_name 'table_B')
```

However, when I query for the `data_type` of the fdw_table I get the following result:

`name   text 
area   double precision
use    text
geom   USER-DEFINED`

Can *fdw_postgres* not handle the GEOMETRY data type of PostGIS? What does USER-DEFINED mean in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html) on the `data_type` column:

> Data type of the column, if it is a built-in type, or `ARRAY` if it is
>   some array (in that case, see the view `element_types`), else
>   `USER-DEFINED` (in that case, the type is identified in `udt_name` and
>   associated columns).

So this is not specific to FDWs; you'd see the same definition for a physical table.

`postgres_fdw` can handle custom datatypes just fine, but there is currently [one caveat](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/postgres-fdw.html#AEN137026): if you query the foreign table with a `WHERE` condition involving a user-defined type, it will not push this condition to the foreign server.

In other words, if your `WHERE` clause only references built-in types, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM fdw_table
WHERE name = $1
```

... then the `WHERE` clause will be sent to the foreign server, and only the matching rows will be retrieved. But when a user-defined type is involved, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM fdw_table
WHERE geom = $1
```

... then the entire table is retrieved from the foreign server, and the filtering is performed locally.

[Postgres 9.6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/postgres-fdw.html#AEN141232) will resolve this, by allowing you to attach a list of extensions to your foreign server object.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: it can be written in the definition/options of the foreign data wrapper e.g.:
`CREATE SERVER foreign_example_server
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER foreign_db 
OPTIONS ( dbname 'testtable', extensions 'postgis');`

Comment: see Postgres-documentation: [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/postgres-fdw.html#id-1.11.7.42.10](Postgres-Homepage: F.33.1.4. Remote Execution Options)

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously you are going to need any non-standard types defined at *both* ends. Don't forget the FDW functionality is supposed to support a variety of different database platforms, so there isn't any magic way to import remote operations on a datatype. Actually, given that one end could be running on MS-Windows and the other on ARM-based Linux there's not even a sensible way of doing it just with PostgreSQL.